# Error occurred prerendering page "/404" and Error for page /_error: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working a project using TypeScript and Next.js. The website is extremely so far simple and only contains a few pages, I keep getting the following error when running `next build` on my project:

```
Automatically optimizing pages .
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error:
Error: Error for page /_error: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export
```

I don't have a custom 404 page because I want it to be handled by the `_error.tsx` page since I have server-side redirecting for trailing slashes. This works when running in a development environment, but dies when I try to build it.

Obviously `_error.tsx` has `getServerSideProps` and should NOT be a static page, so why is it trying to make it one? It is obviously not meant to be one as according to the Next.js documentation, any page that exports `getServerSideProps` will not be one. So why is it throwing an error?!?!?!

If it helps, here's the code for my `_error.tsx` file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Router from 'next/router';

import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

import useStandardHeaderTags from '../lib/useStandardHeaderTags';
import TitleElement from '../components/TitleElement';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  })
);

interface Props {
  statusCode: number;
}

const Error: React.FC<Props> = ({ statusCode }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const title = statusCode === 404 ? '404' : 'Error';

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {useStandardHeaderTags(title)}
      </Head>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <TitleElement text={title} />

        {statusCode === 404
          ? 'The page you are looking for could not be found.'
          : 'An error occurred.'}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ res, req }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : 404;

  if (statusCode === 404) {
    if (req.url.match(/\/$/)) {
      const withoutTrailingSlash = req.url.substr(0, req.url.length - 1);
      if (res) {
        res.writeHead(303, {
          Location: withoutTrailingSlash
        });
        res.end();
      }
      else {
        Router.push(withoutTrailingSlash);
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      statusCode
    }
  };
};

export default Error;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_error.tsx` it's not a regular page but a component to initialize error pages.

Try to use `Error.getInitialProps` instead of `getServerSideProps`.

```
Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
  return { statusCode }
}
```

Also, you should return an object without `props` nesting when using `Error.getInitialProps`.

[Customizing The Error Page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-error-page)

Comment: Using `Error.getInitialProps` solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Using getInitialProps just doesn't allow the page to be statically optimized, it will do fine for the warning but maybe is not what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

create _error.tsx file at the root of your pages folder and populate it with these and run yarn build or push to deployment.

```
import Error from 'next/error';

function Page({ statusCode }: any) {
  return <Error statusCode={statusCode}></Error>;
}

Page.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: { res: any; err: any }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Page;
```